Handling & and ? in Webhook JSON Payload
I am having an issue which I am having a hard time figuring out, and the reps over and SendGrid don't seem to know the answer either. We have a webhook configured to listen to a variety of user events, one of them is a click event in which we capture the Url that was clicked.
The issue we are facing is that when we get the click payload, it is often a broken JSON as it seems like it is cutting of the payload. This only seems to be an issue with the webhook, as the payload I send to my lambda is always fine and correct. Ex, assume I have the following url for an outlook email: `

https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/action/compose%26rru=addevent%26startdt=2024-04-15T15:20:00Z%26enddt=2024-04-15T15:50:00Z%26subject=Session+with+factory+002%26location=%26body=hardcodedTestData

`
The payload we would get that ends up in our dead letter queue for the click event often looks like so:

    [{
"EmailMessageId":"EmailMessage-Id-14ba5bd2-371e-47d6-85c8-fe9a000d1ae9",
"EntityId":"Entity-Id-09f20716-7321-4c77-bfdb-c5d195ad8286",
"UserId":"User-Id-48e59c50-b275-45b6-aea9-63533386e7f9","
category":["Not needed?"],
"email":"redacted",
"event":"click",
"ip":"redacted",
"sg_event_id":"d2i_W8XQSdW2svYz0h0Qtw",
"sg_message_id":"w-zS2DOnQFqvPZT-55CGMA.filterdrecv-5744f46764-9qm8f-1-661D5910-2A.0",
"sg_template_id":"d-7ec0a062a3aa4ee7b1f36c941d1e0dbc",
"sg_template_name":"Coaching Session Invite ","timestamp":1713199507,
"url":"https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/action/compose&rru=addevent&startdt=2024-04-15T15:20:00Z&


Note how the Url is entirely cut off and the payload itself isn't a fully formed JSON (missing closing ], } and "). The way in which I encode the URL on the backend in my lambda is as so:
var emailSubject = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(subject);
var emailLocation = castedData.SessionLocation != null ? HttpUtility.UrlEncode(castedData.SessionLocation) : null;
var emailDescription = "";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(castedData.Description))
{
    emailDescription = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(castedData.Description);
    htmlStrippedDescription = Regex.Replace(castedData.Description, "<(?:[^>\\'\"\"]*|([\\'\"]).*?\\1)*>|&nbsp", String.Empty);
}

var outlookUrl = $"https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/action/compose&rru=addevent&startdt=" +
    $"{castedData.SessionStartTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")}Z" +
    $"&enddt={castedData.SessionEndTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")}Z&subject={emailSubject}" +
    $"&location={emailLocation}&body={emailDescription}";

The way in which the API Gateway converts the data is as follows (adding an image as it is easier). 
Nothing seems awry to me in terms of my set up, all other webhook responses like Open, Delivered, etc. work. It is only the Click event with the url field being completely borked. I even tried coding the & as %26 instead to see if that would fix the issue, it does not. No click events are captured and the url at that point becomes invalid and as such is a non functional link. Because the payload itself is completely broken, I cannot just avoid this issue by not trying to parse out the Url field.
